# django UserPassesTestMixin with parameter

Tags: django, django-permissions

Here's working version with user_passes_test. But I would like to replace position > 1 with parameter. I found that, it's possible to do with UserPassesTestMixin. But I don't know how. Can anyone help?

models.py

```
class user_control(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=CASCADE)    
    position = models.ForeignKey(position, on_delete=CASCADE)
    ...
```

views.py

```
def position_check(user):    
    position = 0 if user.is_anonymous else user_control.objects.values(
            'position__rank'
        ).get(
            user = user.id        
        )

    return True if position > 1 else False

@user_passes_test(position_check, login_url='loginPage')
def index(request):
   pass

@user_passes_test(position_check, login_url='loginPage')
def exportReview(request):
   pass
```

I was try:

```
class PositionCheckMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    position_value = 2    

    def test_func(self):
        position = 0 if user.is_anonymous else user_control.objects.values(
                'position__rank'
            ).get(
                user = self.request.user.id        
            )
    
        return position > self.position_value

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('loginPage')
    
class Review(PositionCheckMixin):
   position_value = 2

   def index(request):
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing class-based views and function-based views. Exactly what do you try to implement?

Comment: I would like to get position__rank of login user and decide if they can access to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a decorator that takes for example an optional parameter:

```
def position_check(function=None, position_value=1, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    def check(user):    
        position = 0 if user.is_anonymous else user_control.objects.values(
            'position__rank'
        ).get(
            user=user.id        
        )
        return position > position_value
    
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        check,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Then you can use the decorator with:

```
@position_check(position_value=42, login_url='loginPage')
def index(request):
    # …
    pass
```

For a class-based view, using the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) is more convenient:

```
class PositionCheckMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    position_value = 1
    
    def test_func(self):
        position = 0 if self.request.user.is_anonymous else user_control.objects.values(
            'position__rank'
        ).get(
            user=self.request.user.id
        )

        return position > self.position_value
```

then you can mix this in a class-based view with:

```
class MyView(PositionCheckMixin, View):
    position_value = 42
    
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks you, I just updated my code. Still not working. It's go direct to index function without checking.

Comment: @TrungVu: but your `index` is a function-based view. You should or decorate it with a decorator, or work with a class-based view, and then override the `get`/`post`/... method.

Comment: I have another question. Please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71570375/django-bulk-create-with-null-value