# django bulk_create with Null value

Tags: django, django-views

models.py

```
class control(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    driver = models.ForeignKey(driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
controlValues = [
    (1,1,1),
    (2,8,None)
]
control.objects.bulk_create([
    control(
        id = i[0],
        amount = i[1],
        driver = driver(id = i[2])
    ) for i in controlValues], ignore_conflicts=True
)
```

I got error:
bulk_create() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'driver'.
How can I set Null for driver? I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is `None`, you should not construct a `driver` model with that object, but thus work with:

```
control.objects.bulk_create([
    control(
        id=id,
        amount=amount,
        driver=driver(id=dr_id) if dr_id is not None else None
    ) for id, amount, dr_id in controlValues],
    ignore_conflicts=True
)
```

or a lot simpler:

```
control.objects.bulk_create([
    control(
        id=id,
        amount=amount,
        driver_id=dr_id
    ) for id, amount, dr_id in controlValues],
    ignore_conflicts=True
)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`driver`</s> to `Driver`.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to run website on local network with https? Right now, I'm using ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.4.241'] with runserver 192.168.4.241:8000 and everything is working fine, but I would like to install django-pwa on that and https is must have.

Comment: Normally you configure this in the nginx/apache/... webserver. For example with https://medium.com/clercode/part-6-integrating-ssl-https-with-django-website-c0d416811037

Comment: Please help me with login page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609244/django-session-security-not-working-for-remember-me